# What is better, if else within loop, or two different loops within if else, with a function call, or same code repeated within if-else?

Tags: php, optimization

So I am trying to optimize a piece of php code that basically runs the same operations on two different datasets, based on user input. What would be a better and more optimized approach?

```
//$input = //user input
//$a = [1,2,3 .....];
//$b = [a,b,c .....];//both are same length - n


case 1 : 

for($i =0; $i<n; $i++) {
    if($input == 'a')
        //doSomething with $a[i] - code here
    else
        //doSomething with $b[i] - code here

}

case 2 : 
if($input == 'a') {
    for($i =0; $i<n; $i++) {
        //doSomething with $a[i] - code here
    }
}
else {
    for($i =0; $i<n; $i++) {
        //doSomething with $b[i] - code here
    }
}



case 3 : 
if($input == 'a') {
    for($i =0; $i<n; $i++) {
        doSomething($a[i]);
    }
}
else {
    for($i =0; $i<n; $i++) {
        doSomething($b[i]);
    }
}
```

the operation is same in all cases

Comment: Did you run any performance tests?

Comment: haven't run any yet. Will do so right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Better* is always difficult to quantify, but if you want to do exactly the same processing on the inputs, just picking the one dataset depending on the input, you may be better off just setting an input array and just processing that...

```
if($input == 'a')
    $dataset = $a;
else
    $dataset = $b;
foreach ( $dataset as $dataItem ) {
    //doSomething data code here
}
```

Comment: You could even use, dare I say, *variable variables*… `$dataset = $$input` (or better have an array of arrays instead of individual variables, validate the input yada yada)…

Comment: @deceze, I just suffer from paranoia and for the sake of a couple of lines of code I like the *it does what it says on the tin* approach.

Comment: Absolutely, there are a ton of caveats that come with using variable variables.

Comment: the issue here is that i only get one of the datasets as inputs from calling method, so either $a is null, or $b is null, the obvious option would be to just club them into the same method, but, due to other critical script, I cannot do that, and it's all about performance optimisation here, as the script would ideally work with records in multiples of 10k,

also, the dosomething is not a simple processing, but a complex set of statements that even include database hits etc.

Answer (score 0):

This might not really be the answer you're looking for, but honestly, I would just go for whatever conveys the actual use case the best and not try to optimize too much.

Performance-wise, unless the operation that checks the `$input` takes a lot of time (orders of magnitude more than a simple comparison), or if the operation on `$dataset` is very short (comparable to the input check), it simply won't matter.

Assuming `$input` does not change while you're processing your dataset, I'd go for case three. You're making it clear that it is the same operation, and the only difference between the different if branches is the dataset you're working with. If you're familiar with ternary operators, I'd even use this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < n; $i++) {
    doSomething(($input == $a) ? $a[i] : $b[i]);
}
```

I'd take code readability over micro-optimizations any day, as long as you don't actually have performance issues with this piece of code.

As a bonus, have a read at this question about optimization: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil